# Redirecting "file://<some html file>" in Flask

Tags: redirect, flask

How can I redirect a local html file in Flask? The local html file, which is outside of (external to) the Flask file/function structure, should be referred to port 80 (apache server, away from python stallion server which listens on port 5000). Thanks

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are wanting to do here. Can you please provide an example and clearer explanation?

Comment: It would seem to be a rather massive glaring security hole for your web-browser to allow a web-server to redirect you to a file on your local computer.  If you could do that, you could post data from a clients computer to a random webserver, without their knowledge using JS.   As Joe said, let us know why and what you're trying to do, rather then how you're trying to solve it.

Comment: First, the webserver is purely for private use (accessed only by the 'localhost'), so the security issue doesn't play a part.

Comment: First, the webserver is purely for private use (accessed only by the 'localhost'), so the security issue doesn't play a part. Second, Stallion (based on Flask) is a tiny webserver that monitors all the installed python packages on my local laptop and keeps track of updates. Besides the (http) hyperlink to the (external) packages' repositories... (continued...)

Comment: (...continuing) ...I also want it hyperlinked to the local package information on my local laptop, i.e. simply just redirecting a href='file:///<path on local laptop to package docu>.html . This <path on .... docu> however doesn't reside in Stallion's template directory. I've tried using a symbolic link from the template directory to the local package docu repository but, alas, to no avail... Hope this information helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you need is the Flask [send_from_directory](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.send_from_directory) function.  It allows you to send a file from any directory on the server.